# Routing Error uninitialized constant ContactFormsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make my first Rails app and have problem with routes.
My routes.rb is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :contact_forms, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  root 'static_pages#home'
  match '/',        to: 'static_pages#home',       via: 'post'
  match '/manager', to: 'static_pages#manager',    via: 'get'
  match '/manager', to: 'sessions#create',         via: 'post'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',        via: 'delete'
end
```

My contact_form_controller.rb is:

```
class ContactFormController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact_form = ContactForm.new
  end

 def create
    @contact_form = ContactForm.new message_params
    @contact_form.save
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Saved"
 end

  private
    def contact_form_params
      params.require(:contact_form).permit(:name, :phone, :email, :text)
    end
end
```

my new.html.erb file is:

```
<%= form_for @contact_form do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>
   <%= f.text_field :phone %>
   <%= f.text_field :email %>
   <%= f.text_field :text %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Whats wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> uninitialized constant ContactFormsController

You should change your ***controller class name*** from `ContactFormController` to `ContactFormsController` and also file name to `contact_forms_controller.rb`

Furthermore in your code, you need to change `@contact_form = ContactForm.new message_params` to `@contact_form = ContactForm.new contact_form_params` in `create` method to avoid any further issues.

And also, as you are trying to create your first app, I suggest you to follwow these [***Guides***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/)

Comment: I've fixed class name, now it: `ContactFormsController`. If file name is contact_forms_controller.rb so I have an error: `NameError in ContactFormsController#create`
`undefined local variable or method `message_params' for #<ContactFormsController:0xb3cb3e88>`

Comment: @verrom I've already notified about that in my answer. Please check :)

Comment: Yes, you are right :) Thank you for advice, I will :)

Answer (score 1):

`resources :contact_forms` defines `ContactFormController`, not `ContactFormsController`. You need to:

1. rename `contact_form_controller.rb` to `contacts_form_controller.rb`
2. fix class name to `ContactFormsController`
3. rename `views/contact_form` to `views/contact_forms`

This should fix your problem.

**Update**

Also update `create` method to this:

```
def create
  @contact_form = ContactForm.new contact_form_params
  @contact_form.save
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "Saved"
end
```

Comment: I tried to fix it,  and have the next error:

`NameError in ContactFormsController#create
undefined local variable or method `message_params' for #<ContactFormsController:0xb4ed9f04>`

Comment: @verrom you need to update `create` method as well (see update)

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should have a plural name to match that route.

So it should be called contact_forms_controllers.rb

and be

```
class ContactFormsController < ApplicationController

   ....
end
```

Your views folder, test controller names will also need to be updated so you may just want to generate a new controller and copy all the content over. (Then remove the old)